# Firemonkey BufferedReader

Tags: android, delphi, stream, firemonkey

I want to read lines from an JInputStream in a thread that should not block.

In Java it is very easy, using `BufferedReader`, `InputStreamReader`, `.ready()` and `.readLine()`. But how do I use these functionalities in Delphi? I did not find a `JBufferedReader` class in the FMX framework.

Here is my current code:

```
var // of TBufLineJStream
  buf: TJavaArray<Byte>;
  FStream: JInputStream;
  FCurIncompleteString: String;
  FReadLines: TQueue<String>;

const // of TBufLineJStream
  BufferSize = 65536;

procedure TBufLineJStream._ReadFromStream;
var
  c: Char;
  i, readCount: integer;
begin
  while FStream.available > 0 do
  begin
    readCount := FStream.read(buf, 0, BufferSize);
    for i := 0 to readCount-1 do
    begin
      c := Chr(buf.Items[i]);
      if c = #13 then
      begin
        // The line is complete
        FReadLines.Enqueue(FCurIncompleteString);
        FCurIncompleteString := '';
      end
      else
      begin
        // The line is not complete yet
        FCurIncompleteString := FCurIncompleteString + c;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TBufLineJStream.ReadLineNonBlocking(var outStr: string): boolean;
begin
  _ReadFromStream;

  result := FReadLines.Count > 0;
  if result then outStr := FReadLines.Dequeue;
end;
```

One some phones it works, on some others it doesn't work. The [Java documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) explains why:

> [...]
>
> Note that this method provides such a weak guarantee that it is not
>   very useful in practice.
>
> Firstly, the guarantee is "without blocking for more input" rather
>   than "without blocking": a read may still block waiting for I/O to
>   complete — [...]
>
> [...]
>
> The default implementation of this method in InputStream always
>   returns 0. Subclasses should override this method if they are able to
>   indicate the number of bytes available.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the Java implementation would work? If you take a look at how `InputStreamReader` handles `ready` (it uses `available` as well) then your code in Delphi should work the same way. What stream are you reading the data from (socket maybe)? I'd suggest some sleeping before checking `available`. If you're absolutely positive that Java uses working implementation, you can always create a wrapper for any Java class yourself (but it is a lot of work). I'd personally suggest creating `TStream` wrapper about Java stream and using `TStreamReader`.

Comment: The stream comes from a BluetoothSocket. It works on some devices, but we have at least one device, where `available` always returns values >0 . Really always. Even if the Stream is empty and nothing was sent for 10 minutes. One device always sends 0 , so the function assumes that there is no data in the stream. Since we only develop in Firemonkey and not with Eclipse+ADT, we had no possibility yet to test if `BufferedReader` works on the problematic devices. But at least `BufferedReader` is recommended in the documentation, while `available` is not recommended for this use.

Comment: I did dig though implementation of `BufferedReader` from OpenJDK (sure Android could use different one but they "should" work the same way), and as I said before it uses `available` pretty much the same way you do. You could try to use some simple Java app to test this and if it helps then I'd suggest creating a Delphi wrapper for  the `BufferedReader`. Aren't there some documentation from the vendor on which device the `available` works the unusual way? I'm not familiar with BT using Delphi on mobile so I'm afraid I cannot assist you further.

Comment: The TBluetoothLE component doesn't work for you?

Comment: @FMXExpress No. The stream comes from a Bluetooth Classic SPP stream.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? A Java Bluetooth socket? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Bluetooth.TBluetoothSocket.ReadData

Comment: And how to do it in a thread with a TCP socket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881685/indy-tcp-read-data-in-a-loop

Comment: I am working with the JNI. The unit I am using is http://www.pclviewer.com/android/Androidapi.JNI.BluetoothAdapter.zip